# Approaches to conversational practice

Tags: learning-methods, speaking, spanish

I am a intermediate-advanced student in Spanish, B2 ish.

I found some really amazing C1-C2 grammar books and I am using that in class with a teacher to study and review topics in order and it's great.

I have a study plan for listening, reading, writing, and grammar, and I use vocabulary apps, but my question is... is there some kind of cirriculum for conversational practice?  I know the communicative approach textbooks that early study get seem kind of like this, but I've been scarred by my secondary school instruction which used these textbooks. I learned nothing in those classes so it kind of left me with a bad taste vis-a-vis those kinds of textbooks. Maybe I'm just looking for an C1-C2 communicative approach textbook?

I just figure, I'm writing, reading, and listening everyday to graded materials, studying graded grammar books, and using an app for vocabulary that's graded, is there accompanying material that can guide conversations? Like graded prompts or roleplays, that go into increasingly uncommon territory, with lists of accompanying vocabulary?

Obviously I don't just sit there and talk about the same thing everytime, but I also never think to bring up certain things that an actual cirriculum might make me think of. Like "in what manner does one talk to a police officer" or "how do you speak at a funeral".

Comment: Hi and welcome to Language Learning Stack Exchange. You wrote "Maybe I'm just looking for an C1-C2 communicative approach textbook?" But you also seem to be asking less explicitly about other approaches. If you are looking for materials, can I ask you to focus on one type of materials, e.g. textbooks? You can always post questions about other type of materials as separate questions.